# OVH Proxmox Install: PHP on VM sees host IP as remote for every request

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, firewall, php

I'm having an odd issue with my Proxmox VM. I've got a VM runnig CentOS 7 with VestaCP for some small websites.
On of the websites needs to be IP Whitelisted so only allowed IP addresses can access this website. As we cannot have user accounts, this needs to be an IP Whitelist.

The issue I am experiencing: The PHP (PHP 7.3) code returns the host (Proxmox host) ip as remote. I cannot find the issue, not in the firewall nor the network adapter. After having searched online with no luck I'm hoping someone here can help!

Setup:
Dedicated server run at OVH with Proxmox VE 6 installed, with 8 "Failover IP's"
VM running CentOS 7, with a bridged Realtek Network adapter connected to one of the FailOver IP's
PHP 7.3 website coded in Laravel

What would be the issue here? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. I've worked with HAProxy, NGinx, and Apache as HTTP proxies and all work this way.

The solution is through the [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header. This header is set by the proxy and identifies the host which originated the request.

There are two parts to solving this problem:

1. configure your proxy to set this header when it forwards a request, and
2. configure your whitelist to look for this header.

**Edit** apparently there's now a standard header for this: [`Forwarded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded)